# UITableView becoming nil when UISearchBar is used

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After a day of trying to debug my problem, I have only got so far - I can see that after I have created my table **and then** searched what for the song I am looking for, the table object becomes nil.

I am unsure to why this occurs, and how I would prevent this from happening. Am I forgetting something? Did I do something incorrectly?

*All the problems started happening when I discovered `.reloadData` on the table 'unexpectedly got a nil error'*

Here is my code so far, it's a little messy from debugging using print statements:

```
import UIKit


protocol Filtering {
    var filteredSongs: [SongDataHandler.SongDataHandlerItem]! { get set }
}


class SongPickerViewController: UIViewController, Filtering, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var SongPicker: UITableView!

    var filteredSongs: [SongDataHandler.SongDataHandlerItem]! {
        didSet {
            print("About to reload...")
            print(SongPicker)

            if let songPicker = SongPicker {
                songPicker.reloadData()
                print("RELOADED DATA")
            }
        }
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toTable" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! UserViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup table
        print("Started setup")
        SongPicker.delegate = self
        SongPicker.dataSource = self
        print("Finished setup, \(SongPicker)")
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("changing table ------")
        if isEditing {
            // Editing
            return filteredSongs.count
        }

        return songHandler.songItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = SongPicker.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        if isEditing {
            // Editing
            cell?.imageView?.image = filteredSongs[indexPath.row].songImage
            cell?.textLabel?.text = filteredSongs[indexPath.row].songName
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredSongs[indexPath.row].songArtist

            return cell!
        }

        cell?.imageView?.image = songHandler[indexPath.row]?.songImage
        cell?.textLabel?.text = songHandler[indexPath.row]?.songName
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = songHandler[indexPath.row]?.songArtist

        return cell!
    }

}
```

Connections work completely as normal.

How my search bar and table look like:

[image]

Search code:

```
import UIKit


var isEditing = false


class UserViewController: UIViewController, Filtering, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var SearchBar: UISearchBar?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    var filteredSongs: [SongDataHandler.SongDataHandlerItem]! {
        didSet {
            print("Detected in userVC")
        }
    }

    var delegate: Filtering?// = SongPickerViewController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Search bar: \(SearchBar!)")
        SearchBar?.delegate = self

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }


    func findSearch(_ searchText: String) {
        print(filteredSongs)

        delegate?.filteredSongs = songHandler.songItems.compactMap { songItem in
            print(songItem.songName.lowercased())
            print(searchText.lowercased())
            if songItem.songName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                print("match!")
                return songItem
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        print("Filtered songs: \(filteredSongs)")

        // Update table
        print("table delecate: \(delegate)")
    }

}



extension UserViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        print("checking")
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("search (clicked)")
        findSearch(searchBar.text!)
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isEditing = true
    }
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isEditing = false
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing search?, seems to be a fair amount of code missing from the question

Comment: Is your view controller initialized from a storyboard?  Is the IBOutlet connected?

Comment: @kid_x Connected to the storyboard using `IBOutlet` and the connections are completely fine

Comment: At some point are you removing / replacing / somehow unloading your vc's view?  Since the outlet is weak, it's your view that's maintaining the strong reference to it.  If it gets deallocated, so will your tableView.

Comment: @Scriptable Searching doesn't seem to have any problems, it's the updating of the table

Comment: @kid_x So you suggest I should make the table a strong reference? The table view is just underneath the search bar (within UIView)

Comment: "All the problems started happening when I discovered .reloadData on the table 'unexpectedly got a nil error'" - you reload data when you search... it's quite likely that its got everything to do with search

Comment: Don't make it a strong reference.  It shouldn't be necessary.  I only mention it to help reason with your tableView's life cycle.

Comment: If you're manipulating filteredSongs on the segue, it's possible you're doing it too early.  Your tableView won't exist until viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: @kid_x Added the search code (different swift file, but still all properly linked together, I'm mostly sure)

Comment: @kid_x My table loads fine, as shown in comments in code as well (does not return nil). However, when I press enter after searching my song name it makes the table object nil (also commented in first section of code)

Comment: I'm sure it loads fine.  It's a question of when in loads.  When you invoke delegate?.filteredSongs = songHandler.songItems.compactMap, your setter presumably gets called, but is your table already visible at that point?  I assume you don't show the table if you don't have results.  If so, when calling findSearch(...), your tableView doesn't exist yet.  It's the only thing I can thing of, with the code you've provided here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving all my code to one view controller, it worked perfectly with no problems. I guess I just overcomplicated it, as there was absolutely no need for two view controllers.

PS. `isEditing` in my original code is part of `UIViewController`, so use `isEditingSearch` or something like that to prevent an override error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

`var delegate: Filtering? = SongPickerViewController()`

You are setting the delegate to a **new** instance of the view controller that hasn't had it's view loaded, or the outlets connected.

What you need to do.. You haven't shown enough code for a precise answer, so I'm going to make some guesses/assumptions.

So the user taps a button or something, to goto the UserViewController with a segue (presumption)

so somewhere you may have a call to `performSegueWithIdentifier`

then you need a `prepareForSegue` method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "myIdentifier" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? UserViewController {
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

This way you set the delegate to the actual instance of `SongPickerViewController` that you are using and has its view loaded.

UPDATE: After looking at the source code, the UserViewController is a parent view controller and SongPickerController is an embedded ViewController in a container. After chatting with the OP, I advised an alternative structure for the problem so the op is going to rework the issue.

Comment: I think you are right... so how shall I make this to one instance which never changes?

Comment: This is definitely your issue, I knew it would be. I've updated the answer with an example, but basically you need to pass Self (the SongPickerViewController) to the UserViewController rather than creating a new one

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense.  You're not choosing the controller you created from the storyboard, but rather one you initialized yourself, independent of the storyboard and the segue.

Comment: Assign your delegate on the segue as Scriptable describes above.  It won't be one instance that never changes, but it will be the instance that is created on the segue, and thus the one you are seeing onscreen.

Comment: @Scriptable Unfortunately, it still does not seem to solve my problem... hmm

Comment: I will try get rid of the containerView as that might be causing a slight issue

Comment: It should... show your updated code in an edit to your question

Comment: @George_E_2 verify your didSet is called after the segue is called.  If the segue is called first, your tableView definitely won't exist yet, as its parent view hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: If the SongPickerController is loaded first and then the user moves to UserViewController by segue, the SongPickerController should defo be loaded and ready. something is not right with the implementation. We need more info

Comment: The controller is loaded, but not its view.  Views are lazily allocated when needed.

Comment: @kid_x I do not get anything when putting a print within the segue prepare function, as I think this is because it is a container view

Comment: are you actually using segues? please show how a user gets from SongPickerController to loading UserViewController

Comment: @Scriptable Shall I just send you my whole project? I am totally lost

Comment: I may be wrong, but as a test, could you call .isViewLoaded on your destination controller in the segue?  Maybe I'm totally off.

Comment: sure, share the updated source and I will take a look